# Java interface inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I've written this code:

```
package sample;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusInterface;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusInterfaceName;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection;

@DBusInterfaceName("org.mpris.clementine")
interface Player extends DBusInterface, java.rmi.Remote {
    void Pause();
}


class Main {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusException, java.lang.InterruptedException {
                DBusConnection dc = DBusConnection.getConnection(DBusConnection.SESSION);
                Player player = (Player) dc.getRemoteObject("org.mpris.clementine", "/Player");
                player.Pause();
                dc.disconnect();
        }
}
```

And get a mistake in line

```
Player player = (Player) dc.getRemoteObject("org.mpris.clementine", "/Player");
```

It says that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy2 cannot be cast to sample.Player
```

I know that the problem is in inheritance misunderstanding or smth like that. I've searched thoroughly but I couldn't find an answer. How to write this line correctly? And what's the mistake?

Comment: the problem is that you think you'll be getting something that extends/implements Player, but youre not. youre getting some sort of auto-generated proxy that doesnt extend/implement Player. maybe its a List<Player> ? i dont know. i'd recommend setting a breakpoint there and running a few instanceof checks to see what you have. could you maybe post the other side of this connection? what are you "binding" under "/Player" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the class returned by

```
 dc.getRemoteObject
```

implements the interface Player

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
Object obj = dc.getRemoteObject("org.mpris.clementine", "/Player");
if( obj instanceof Player ) {
    Player player = (Player) obj;
    player.pause();
}
```

Comment: Alex K, I used this but I get the same mistake in line

Comment: The error is, that the object you get from `dc.getRemoteObject()` implements `DBusInterface`, but not `Player`. To be able to cast it to `Player`, the inheritance sequence would have to be the other way around, like `DBusInterface extends Player`.
Right now there is no 'pause()' method implementation the program could run. The test with `instanceof` should prevent the cast from being executed, and it did so in my test.

Comment: also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656268/accessing-clementine-instance-via-d-bus-mpris-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what does 'dc.getRemoteObject()', if its a remote operation you would need to un-marshal the object.

> Object obj=  dc.getRemoteObject("org.mpris.clementine", "/Player");
>
> Player  player =(Player )PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj,Player.class)